# How to filter data in one List from data in another?

Tags: c#

I have two identically sized Lists in my application. One contains date information, and the other contains the water conductivity data for that date. I am using the two Lists to plot information on a graph. I am now attempting to add a slider which allows the user to filter the data by a certain number of days. Here is my code so far:

```
// Filter the date data (this works!)
var filteredDates = from n in parsedDateList[0]
                    where n >= beginDate.Date
                    select n;

//Filter the y-axis data (this does not work!)
var filteredCond = waterConductivityList[1].Where(x => parsedDateList[0].Any(y=> y.Date > beginDate));
```

Could someone fill me in on what I am doing wrong? The y-axis filter simply returns the full list of information rather than filtering.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Dictionary<DateTime, WaterConductivity>`?

Comment: I'm not seeing how that works... could someone explain this further?

Comment: Go with Tim's suggestion. However, just to explain what you experiencing: Look at your Where clause for filteredCond. You can take the part "parsedDateList[0].Any(y=> y.Date > beginDate)" out of the Where clause, like `bool b = parsedDateList[0].Any(y=> y.Date > beginDate);`. So your Where clause is equivalent to `Where(x => b)`. Regarding this Where clause, `b` is **always** either *true* or *false* -- it does not change inside the Where clause, regardless of **x**. Do you see that?

Comment: @JohnAugust: you have two lists which logically belong together because every day has one `WaterConductivity`. Since the day is also unqiue you can use a `Dictionary<DateTime,WaterConductivity>` with the date as key(use `DateTime.Date` to truncate time) and the `WaterConductivity` as value. Then you just have to lookup it in this way: `WaterConductivity forToday = dateWaterConductivityMapping[DateTime.Today];`.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the explanation, I am going to give it a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, int> conductivityData = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

// Get the y-values
i=0;
foreach (var entry in waterConductivityData[1])
            {
                condData[i] = Convert.ToInt32(entry);
                i++;
            }

// Add the dates ("entry" from datelist) and the y-value (condData) to the dictionary
i=0;
foreach (var entry in parsedDateList[0])
            {
                    conductivityData.Add(entry, condData[i]);
                    i++;
            }

//Add the data to the plot series using "key" for dates and "value" for y-data
foreach (var entry in conductivityData)
                    {
                            filteredDateStrings[0].Add(entry.Key.ToString("M/d/yy hh:mm tt"));
                            filteredCondData[0].Add(entry.Value);
                    }

// Update plot data
                i = 0;
                foreach (var entry in filteredCondData[0])
                {
                    waterSourceTwoChart.Series["conductivity"].Points.AddXY(filteredDateStrings[0].ElementAt(i), filteredCondData[0].ElementAt(i));
                    i++;
                }
```

Thanks everyone for the help!